# Appending multiple bool filters to a NEST query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'd like to append multiple bool filters with NEST, but I can't (practically) do it in a single statement as I want to build a set of **Bool** filters depending on different conditions.

Something like this pseudo code:

```cs
// Append a filter
searchDescriptor.Filter(f => f.Bool(b => b.Must(m => m.Term(i => i.SomeProperty, "SomeValue"))));

if (UserId.HasValue)
{
   // Optionally append another filter (AND condition with the first filter)
   searchDescriptor.Filter(f => f.Bool(b => b.Must(m => m.Term(i => i.AnotherProperty, "MyOtherValue"))));
}

var result = Client.Search(searchDescriptor);
```

Now it seems when the second optional filter is appended, it essentially replaces the first filter.

I'm sure I'm missing something syntactically, but I can't figure it out and the NEST documentation is a bit thin on the filter DSL. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The section on writing queries pretty much applies to filters as well:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-queries.html

The solution you ended up with is less than ideal since you are wrapping `bool` filters inside an `and` filter which have very different caching mechanisms (and filters don't use the cached bitsets so in most cases perform worse then regular bool filters).

Highly recommend reading http://www.elastic.co/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/ as it explains really well what the differences between and/or/not filters vs bool filters are.

You can actually rewrite this like so:

```cs
Client.Search(s=>s
    .Filter(f=> { 
        BaseFilter ff = f.Term(i => i.MyProperty, "SomeValue");
        if (UserId.HasValue)
            ff &= f.Term(i => i.AnotherProperty, "AnotherValue");
        return ff;
    })
);
```

If the second term is searching using UserId you can take advantage of NEST's `conditionless queries`

```cs
Client.Search(s=>s
    .Filter(f=> 
        f.Term(i => i.MyProperty, "SomeValue") 
        && f.Term(i => i.AnotherProperty, UserId)
    )
);
```

If `UserId` is null then the term query won't be generated as part of the query, nest in this case won't even wrap the single remaining term in a bool filter but just send it as a plain term filter instead.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, something like this seems to work:

```cs
        var filters = new List<BaseFilter>();

        // Required filter
        filters.Add(new FilterDescriptor<MyType>().Bool(b => b.Must(m => m.Term(i => i.MyProperty, "SomeValue"))));

        if (UserId.HasValue)
        {
            filters.Add(new FilterDescriptor<MyType>().Bool(b => b.Must(m => m.Term(i => i.AnotherProperty, "AnotherValue"))));
        }

        // Filter with AND operator
        searchDescriptor.Filter(f => f.And(filters.ToArray()));

        var result = Client.Search(searchDescriptor);
```